# Htaccess using regex to redirect URL is encoding string

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /entrar-na-sua-conta.html\?redirecionar=/([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.portal-gestao.com/%1? [L,R=302]
```

But this is redirecting:

https://www.portal-gestao.com/entrar-na-sua-conta.html?redirecionar=/f%C3%B3rum-perguntas-e-respostas/conversation/read.html?id=25

To:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/f%25C3%25B3rum-perguntas-e-respostas/conversation/read.html?id=25%3f
```

It seems htaccess is encoding the URL and thus returning a 404 error.
Is there a way to redirect to the correct url, like:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/fórum-perguntas-e-respostas/conversation/read.html?id=25%3f
```

Comment: Isn't this your third question about the same URL encoding issue? How did the last answer affect your goal so far? If this is about double-URL-encoding, try the [`[NE]`-flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne).

Comment: Yes! It is my 3rd question and I am getting PARANOID! [NE] made it, thank you!